# Micro optimization - compiler optimization when accesing recursive members

Tags: c++, micro-optimization, pointer-to-member

I'm interested in writing good code from the beginning instead of optimizing the code later. Sorry for not providing benchmark I don't have a working scenario at the moment. Thanks for your attention!

What are the performance gains of using FunctionY over FunctionX?

There is a lot of discussion on stackoverflow about this already but I'm in doubts in the case when accessing sub-members (recursive) as shown below. Will the compiler (say VS2008) optimize FunctionX into something like FunctionY?

```
void FunctionX(Obj * pObj)
{
   pObj->MemberQ->MemberW->MemberA.function1();
   pObj->MemberQ->MemberW->MemberA.function2();
   pObj->MemberQ->MemberW->MemberB.function1();
   pObj->MemberQ->MemberW->MemberB.function2();
   ..
   pObj->MemberQ->MemberW->MemberZ.function1();
   pObj->MemberQ->MemberW->MemberZ.function2();
}

void FunctionY(Obj * pObj)
{
   W * localPtr = pObj->MemberQ->MemberW;
   localPtr->MemberA.function1();
   localPtr->MemberA.function2();
   localPtr->MemberB.function1();
   localPtr->MemberB.function2();
   ...
   localPtr->MemberZ.function1();
   localPtr->MemberZ.function2();
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled this code to see if it's actually slow?

Comment: "writing good code" and "optimizing" are two completely different things and are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case none of the member pointers are volatile or pointers to volatile and you don't have the `operator ->` overloaded for any members in a chain both functions are the same.
The optimization rule you suggested is widely known as Common Expression Elimination and is supported by vast majority of compilers for many decades.

Comment: Thanks, Common Expression Elimination is the term that directed me to more useful information.

Comment: This.  The two code examples are not likely to perform any differently.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you save on the extra pointer dereferences, HOWEVER, in the real world, the compiler will probably optimize it out for you, so it's a useless optimization.

This is why it's important to profile first, and then optimize later.  The compiler is doing everything it can to help you, you might as well make sure you're not just doing something it's already doing.

Comment: Optimization makes good code bad.  "Good Code" is simple, clean and correct.  Only make it worse when the profiler (and other information) tell you something needs to be optimized.

Comment: @JonathanSeng Good code also has to be readable, and in this scenario declaring an explicit variable makes the code much easier to read and understand.

Comment: If actually gained quite some performance with something like this (after profiling though), but there the function was bigger and the `functionX` calls where more spread out. The result of an intermediate variable was that members were in cache more often.

Comment: @UnknownGosu You are correct.  The point is to focus on the readability, not the optimization.  If you get both, that's nice too.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. Sometimes it is more readable to write as in FunctionX if the code in it is really big and you want to have instant idea about the variables

Answer (score 0):

if the compiler is good enough, it should translate functionX into something similar to functionY.
But you can have different result on different compiler and on the same compiler with different optimization flag.
Using a "dumb" compiler functionY should be faster, and IMHO it is more readable and faster to code. So stick with functionY

ps. you should take a look at some code style guide, normally member and function name should always start with a low-case letter

Comment: Thanks! I used upper case only to make them different then other parts of the code to better reflect my question.